# PHP mysqli multi query empty results

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

Im using mysqli multi query to do some inserts and updates in one big lump instead of doing them in lots of seperate queries, basically I don't care about the results even if it is an error and ive read on the PHP.net doc page for the multi_query function I can use this:

```
while ($mysqli->next_result()) {;}
```

to go through the results so I can execute more queries. But the problem here seems to be that each loop of that is taking forever to run, if i replace the ; with `echo "Next";` its like a half a second between each next being echoed.

Any way i can speed this up, or empty the results or something?

Comment: What do your queries look like? Try optimizing your database.

Comment: They're not really big queries, just inserting/updating a few ints in the database. But there is sometimes alot of queries in the string im passing to multi_query. The table has lots of rows if that could make a difference? (~220,000)

Comment: I think it could, somehow, which is why I also suggested running optimize on your database.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't make any difference unfortunatley

Comment: did you use the exact setup displayed on PHP.net? `http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php` - if not, try so, if you did, I guess you need to optimize the data(base) you're running the query on.

Comment: OP says, "if i replace the `;` with `echo "Next";` its like a half a second": the problem is not a db optimization problem. Come on, be a little creative.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY ...
```

And

```
INSERT DELAYED ...
```

If you are using the MyISAM storage engine